# Tableau CONTAINS and CONDITIONAL query

Tags: if-statement, case, tableau-api

I'm just after some help in writing the below IF statement in Tableau. I want to identify when a brand name CONTAINS "McDonald's" but also tell me if the person has shopped at one or two or three or four etc. competitor brands (there are 20 brands listed under [M Brand Name]). This is what I have at the moment but it keeps returning "McDonald's and six or more brands"

```
IF CONTAINS ([M Brand Name], "McDonald's") AND {COUNTD([M Brand Name])} <=2 THEN "McDonald's plus one brand"
ELSEIF CONTAINS ([M Brand Name], "McDonald's") AND {COUNTD([M Brand Name])} <=3 THEN "McDonald's plus two brands"
ELSEIF CONTAINS ([M Brand Name], "McDonald's") AND {COUNTD([M Brand Name])} <=4 THEN "McDonald's plus three brands"
ELSEIF CONTAINS ([M Brand Name], "McDonald's") AND {COUNTD([M Brand Name])} <=5 THEN "McDonald's plus four brands"
ELSEIF CONTAINS ([M Brand Name], "McDonald's") AND {COUNTD([M Brand Name])} <=6 THEN "McDonald's plus five brands"
ELSE "McDonald's and six or more brands"
END
```

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly I think its an issue with the logic. If its just one variable containing 20 distinct brands including "McDonald's" the first part of every if statement is going to be true and for the second part its going to be 20 every time so its correctly pulls back the result "McDonald's and six or more brands".

Comment: You are exactly right - my logic is off and I can see that now. Okay great thanks and I'll try again!